# How to anchor my slider with text on both sides?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

how do I add a text on either side of the slider which says, “Strongly agree” and “Strongly Disagree”?

Thanks alot :)

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<p><font color="black">Right now I feel: Attentive</p>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.01"         class="slider" id="myRange">
<p><font color="black">Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>


<script>
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider1.value;

slider1.oninput = function() {
output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for it.

CSS

```
.slidecontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.slider {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
Right now I feel: Attentive
<div class="slidecontainer">
<span>Strongly agree</span><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.01"         class="slider" id="myRange"><span>Strongly Disagre</span>
</div>
<font color="black">Value: <span id="demo"></span>
```

JS

```
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider1.value;

slider1.oninput = function() {
output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/4p6fgnLu/2/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, made my day honestly. Much appreciated